# NSubstitute 'Do' event not firing

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I have an issue with NSubstitute compiling using its inference typing. When I set it up with more than a return type in my `.Do()` statement and then try and use a counter to see how many times it is called, the counter isn't updated.

I am mocking a method that returns a string (it's basically an abstraction of `File.ReadAllText()`):

```
int fileReadCount =0;

IFileDataSource fs = Substitute.For<IFileDataSource>();

fs.When(x => x.ReadAllText(Arg.Any<string>())).Do(x =>
            {
                fileReadCount++;
                return "test";
            });
```

The alternate form mentioned in the  documentation does seem to work either:

```
        fs.ReadAllText("test").ReturnsForAnyArgs(x =>
        {
            fileReadCount++;
            return "test";
        });
```

My counter never changes.

I am following the examples from http://nsubstitute.github.com/help/return-from-function/ so I don't understand what I am doing wrong - has the API changed?

Comment: Are you injecting the IFileDataSource anywhere? If so, mind posting your test code?

Comment: As an aside, all code samples in NSub documentation are [compiled and run](http://www.davesquared.net/2010/10/interesting-documentation.html) against the latest release, so if it's in the docs it should work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in NSubstitute 1.1:

```
public interface IFileDataSource {
    string ReadAllText(string s);
}

[Test]
public void TestName() {
    int fileReadCount = 0;
    var fs = Substitute.For<IFileDataSource>();
    fs.ReadAllText("test").ReturnsForAnyArgs(x =>
       {
           fileReadCount++;
           return "test";
       });

    fs.ReadAllText("sdf");
    fs.ReadAllText("sdf");
    Assert.AreEqual(fileReadCount, 2);
}
```

Can you post some more code to show the problem?